# WP Query Args - Title or Taxonomy Value

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, search, title

How do I query by tax_value or title?

I have

```
$args = array(
    '_meta_or_title' => sanitize_text_field(preg_replace('/%20/', '+', $query[1])),
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' =>  array('product'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms' => array(13,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,1223,1226,1519, 1658, 890)
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_designer',
            'terms'         => sanitize_text_field(preg_replace('/%20/', '+', $query[1])),
            'field'         => 'name',
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),
        'relation' => 'AND'
    )
);
```

and in functions.php I have

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q )
{
    if( $title = $q->get( '_meta_or_title' ) )
    {
        add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $title )
        {
            global $wpdb;

            // Only run once:
            static $nr = 0; 
            if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

            // Modify WHERE part:
            $sql['where'] = sprintf(
                " AND ( %s OR %s ) ",
                $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title = '%s'", $title ),
                mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
            );
            return $sql;
        });
    }
});
```

but I understand that that is for meta values and not for taxonomies. How should I change what I have in order to have the query look for post title or taxonomy value?